# Adding a dynamically sized view (height) to a UIScrollView with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

Here is my structure of views for this detail view (blogging application, I want to view the entire post which has dynamic height inside of a scrollview):

```
UIView
  -UIScrollView
    -SinglePostView (custom view)
      -Title
      -Subtitle
      -Content
```

Normally to add a 'single post view' to a UIView I simply instantiate it, feed it my Post object and then add a single constraint that pins the width of the singlePostView to the superview, at which point things get laid out nicely. However when I try to add it to a scroll view, it doesn't show up nor does it scroll.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

NOBSinglePostView *singlePost = [[NOBSinglePostView alloc] initWithPost:self.post];
[scrollView addSubview:singlePost];
singlePost.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView,singlePost);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[singlePost]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the structure you are presenting, using AutoLayout, the `contentSize` of your `UIScrollView` is driven by the `intrinsicContentSize` of its subviews, here your `SinglePostView`.

The problem is, `SinglePostView` being a subclass of `UIView`, its `intrinsicContentSize` is always `CGSizeZero` when considered by itself. What you need to do is make the `intrinsicContentSize` of your `SinglePostView` depend on the `intrinsicContentSize` of its subviews.

Then, because the subviews of your `SinglePostView` are `UILabels`, and because a `UILabel`'s `intrinsicContentSize` is the smallest size it needs to display its content, your `SinglePostView`'s `intrinsicContentSize` will be equal to the sum of its subviews `intrinsicContentSizes`, that is the total size needed to display the content of all three of your labels.

Here is how to do it.

## Step 1: Removing all automatically set constraints

First, as you partially did, you need to remove all constraints automatically set by the system.

Assuming you don't have any constraints set in your storyboard or XIB (or you don't even have one of these), just do:

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
singlePost.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
subtitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
contentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Now you have a clear slate and you can start setting your own constraints.

## Step 2: Constraining the `scrollView`

First, let's create, as you did, the views references dictionary for AutoLayout to use:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, singlePost, titleLabel, subtitleLabel, contentLabel);
```

Then, also as you already did, let's constrain the scroll view to be the size of its superview:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
```

## Step 3: Constraining the `SinglePostView` to push the `scrollView`'s `contentSize`

For this step to be clear, you have to understand that every constraints set between a `UIScrollView` and its `subviews` will actually change the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`, not its actual `bounds`. For Example, if you constrain a `UIImageView` to the borders of its parent `UIScrollView` and then put an image twice the size of the `UIScrollView` inside the `UIImageView`, your image won't get shrunk, its the `UIImageView` that will take the size of its image and become scrollable inside the `UIScrollView`.

So here is what you have to set here:

```
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[singlePost]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[singlePost]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:singlePost
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:scrollView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        multiplier:1.0f
                                                          constant:0.0f]];
```

First two constraints are pretty obvious. The third one, however, is here because, for your `UILabels` to display their content properly and still be readable, you will probably want them to be multilined and the scrolling to be vertical, not horizontal. That's why you set your `SinglePostView`'s `width` to be the same as your `scrollView`'s. This way, you prevent your `scrollView`'s `contentSize.width` to be anything more than its `bounds.width`.

## Step 4: Constraining your `UILabels` to "push" the bounds of your `SinglePostView`

Fourth and final step, you now need to set constraints on your `SinglePostView`'s subviews, so that it gets an `intrinsicContentSize` from them.

Here is how you do it (simplest implementation, no margins, one label after the other vertically):

```
[singlePost addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[titleLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
[singlePost addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[subtitleLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
[singlePost addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[contentLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
[singlePost addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[titleLabel]-0-[subtitleLabel]-[contentLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
```

And with that you should be done.

One last advice, you should definitely look into `UIStoryboard` to do these kinds of things. It's a lot simpler and more visual.

Hope this helps,

P.S.: If you want, I can take some time and push a project using both `UIStoryboard` and the `Visual Format Language` on Github. Just tell me if you would need one.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the great description. Step 3 and ensuring the contentsize's width was bounded was the missing link

Comment: @Msencenb What if scrollView's height shrink (same width) on iPhone 4S ?   I have the same structure like this and it has five same sized UIViews on ScrollView. Users are only allowed to scroll horizontally . It works perfect on iPhone 5, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus. However, when scrollView's height shrinks  (intentionally due to content hugging and content resist ) on iPhone 4, my UIView doesn't fit well. I have to scroll down vertically to see a whole pic, but that's not I want. I've check scrollView content size' height, it is the same as on iPhone 5.

Comment: Kudos for referencing intrinsicContentSize for uiscrollviews. I thought I was losing it as I had custom uiviews that needed instrinsicContentSize overrides.

Answer (score 0):

in auto layout

frame of `scrollview` is decided by constraints between `scrollview` and `superview` of `scrollview`.
`contentSize` of `scrollview` is decided by constraints between `scrollview` and `subview` of `scrollview`.

you should set the size of `singlePostView`. `ScrollView` calculate `contentSize` from it. (you need to add size constraints explicitly)

```
CGFloat heightOfSinglePostView = calculate..
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[singlePost(heightOfSinglePostView)]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Comment: What if I don't know the height of the singlePostView prior to it being put out on screen? Are you saying that I need to manually calculate the height itself (using NSString + image height methods)? That seems like the exact opposite of what Auto Layout is intended for

Comment: If content view has intrinsic size (like UIImageView) , it's not need to.  But if not I think content size is need to calculated.  I'll test more to figure out better solution. If you already found, please let me know