# UIScrollView and Autolayout without Interface Builder - how does the scroll view get its height?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm getting to grips with Xcode 6 and iOS autolayout/constraints **without** using Interface Builder/storyboards but am currently struggling with scroll views.

I've written the following code (all longhand while I'm learning!) which drops a scroll view on screen that contains a content view, which in turn contains a couple of additional views.

The scroll event fires fine when I scroll. The problem I have is that the scroll view simply springs back to the start when I let go, which suggests that it's not receiving a content height. I think. Or, maybe I've screwed up the constraints somewhere?

Can anyone give me some pointers as to where I might be going wrong with this?

Thanks.

```
class TestScrollController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var contentView = UIView()
    var blueView = UIView()
    var orangeView = UIView()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var superView = self.view

        var scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        superView.addSubview(scrollView);

        var contentView = UIView()
        contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        let blueView = UIView()
        blueView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        blueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        contentView.addSubview(blueView);

        let orangeView = UIView()
        orangeView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        orangeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        contentView.addSubview(orangeView);




        //scrollview Constraints
        let scrollViewConstraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: scrollView,
            attribute: .Top,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView,
            attribute: .Top,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(scrollViewConstraintTop)

        let scrollViewConstraintRight = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: scrollView,
            attribute: .Trailing,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView,
            attribute: .Right,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(scrollViewConstraintRight)

        let scrollViewConstraintBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: scrollView,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(scrollViewConstraintBottom)

        let scrollViewConstraintLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: scrollView,
            attribute: .Leading,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView,
            attribute: .Left,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(scrollViewConstraintLeft)



        //contentView Constraints
        let contentViewConstraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: contentView,
            attribute: .Top,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: scrollView,
            attribute: .Top,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(contentViewConstraintTop)

        let contentViewConstraintRight = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: contentView,
            attribute: .Trailing,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: scrollView,
            attribute: .Right,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(contentViewConstraintRight)

        let contentViewConstraintBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: contentView,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: scrollView,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(contentViewConstraintBottom)

        let contentViewConstraintLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: contentView,
            attribute: .Leading,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: scrollView,
            attribute: .Left,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(contentViewConstraintLeft)



        //blueView Constraints
        let blueViewConstraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: blueView,
            attribute: .Height,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 100.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(blueViewConstraintHeight)

        let blueViewConstraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: blueView,
            attribute: .Top,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: contentView,
            attribute: .Top,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 50.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(blueViewConstraintTop)

        let blueViewConstraintLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: blueView,
            attribute: .Leading,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView,
            attribute: .Left,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 50.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(blueViewConstraintLeft)

        let blueViewConstraintRight = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: blueView,
            attribute: .Trailing,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView,
            attribute: .Right,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: -50.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(blueViewConstraintRight)



        //orangeView Constraints
        let orangeViewConstraintWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: orangeView,
            attribute: .Width,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 100.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(orangeViewConstraintWidth)

        let orangeViewConstraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: orangeView,
            attribute: .Height,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 100.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(orangeViewConstraintHeight)


        let orangeViewConstraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: orangeView,
            attribute: .Top,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: blueView,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 400.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(orangeViewConstraintTop)

        let orangeViewConstraintBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: orangeView,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: contentView,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 400.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(orangeViewConstraintBottom)


        let orangeViewConstraintCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: orangeView,
            attribute: .CenterX,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: blueView,
            attribute: .CenterX,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0
        )
        superView.addConstraint(orangeViewConstraintCenterX)


    }




    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        println("scrollViewDidScroll")
    }




}
```

Comment: you can find here a very good explanation (in obj-c) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24972208/2477632

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.contentsize(CGRECT)` to set the size of the content *inside* the `UIScrollView`
Since you didn’t set a `contentSize` you cannot scroll towards anything