# How to implement autolayout over uiscrollview?

Tags: ios

please suggest any nice tutorial link, for autolayout over uiscrollview using stroyboard.
Thanks.

Comment: Show your design and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Best explanation here http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24972208/1570169. This is by far the best explanation of understanding UIScrollview with AutoLayout. You shouldn't need to manually set the contentSize of the scrollview. The key is understanding the intrinsicContentSize of the scrollview's main content view which will determine the scrollable area along with some basic constraints for the scrollview itself.

Comment: @N J Gadhiya, i cannot able to post image as i need at least 10 reputations.

Answer (score 0):

Take one scroll view. Assign top, bottom, left and right constraint. Add your content into scroll view. Make sure your scroll view content size would be larger than your scroll view, to make your content scroll inside scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the issue is the scroll view scrolls horizontally too, i only need vertical scroll.

Comment: Check your content size. Scroll view scrolls horizontally if width of content size is greater than scroll view width. Make your content size width equal to scroll view width.